# Cannot drop a single enum value in postgres

Tags: postgresql, enums, alter

I have one table my_table with a column my_column with type my_type('value1', 'value2', 'value3'). I want to remove 'value3'. I read that values for enums are not supposed to be removed... but that it could be achieved by doing this :

- create new type **my_type_NEW**
- modify columns in order to only use **my_type_NEW**
- drop **my_type**
- rename **my_type_NEW** to **my_type** :(.

I tried :

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER my_column type text
CREATE TYPE my_type_new AS ENUM ('value1', 'value2')
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER my_column type my_type_new using my_column::my_type_new 
DROP TYPE my_type;
ALTER TYPE my_type_new RENAME TO my_type
```

At the end, 'value3' is still there. I can't see why.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the table contains `value3` and fails.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER my_column type my_type_new using my_column::my_type_new
```

**[db<>fidde demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1cd1658174fb48e05369cfbb664101d3)**

Before trying to alter column, update should be performed

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_column = NULL   -- or any other
WHERE my_column = 'value3';
```

**[db<>fiddle demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7def0e2f1e576e585606999b54f1dd9c)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately the table is empty. I got no error message while performing the commands. It's just that at the end the new type has exactly the same values as the old one.

Answer (score 0):

The value is actually removed from the enum. The schema in intellij is not properly synchronized / refreshed. The "Database Tools / Forget Cached Schemas" item menu doesn't work :

The auto-generated definition displayed by double-clicking on the enum type is wrong. I'll try to reach the intellij support.